# Codeigniter URI Language Identifier + Tank Auth activation not working just on default language

Tags: codeigniter, uri, identifier

I have a codeigniter 2.2.6 with latest URI Language Identifier and Tank auth installed the problem is when switch to the not default language in my case:
"http://www.mywebsite.hu/en" and proceed registration the email successfully sent but when i click activation link like "http://www.mywebsite.hu/auth/activate/1/8ef760c2345d21654ae92f5a70017f5e" iam get the "The activation code you entered is incorrect or expired." error message.

Then if i am clear the corresponding cookies to mywebsite.hu in the browser the activation is successfully complete. I dont know why...

in codeigniter config.php

```
$config['language'] = "hungarian";

/* default language abbreviation */
$config['language_abbr'] = "hu";

/* set available language abbreviations */
$config['lang_uri_abbr'] = array("en" => "english");

/* hide the language segment (use cookie) */
$config['lang_ignore'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: I think you should set lang abbr before auth in email `APPPATH . 'views/email/activate-html.php'` template around line 17. You should set it by session/cookie you are using for current client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now i'm modified the controller auth.php activate function

from this:

```
$user_id        = $this->uri->segment(3);
$new_email_key  = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

to this:

```
$user_id        = $this->uri->segment(1);
$new_email_key  = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

and now works fine!